# CSS or JS: "dots" into text/image animation?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I saw several time in youtube videos (but i can't find any of them now) that the logo in the opening of the video is starting as many dots that move together to form a logo or words.

Is there a css or js library that do it?

Comment: I dont see that happening (usefully) with css any-time soon. As for Javascript - sure, more than likely. But as far as effects go, it's pretty straight-forward - why not just implement it yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you want/need is ASCII  Art.